# Load Google Maps Android API version based on Android platform

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-version, supportmapfragment

I have an Android application that runs Google Maps API v2. By using SupportMapFragment, I support devices running Android as back as API 8. I know Google Maps API v1 is deprecated and that very few devices run Android API 7 or lower, but is there an easy way to define my layout such that for devices lower than API 8, Google Maps API v1 will be loaded?

Comment: Do you have a Maps V1 API key? If not, there is no point in bothering with this, as you cannot use Maps V1.

Comment: I feel it would be an unnecessary amount of effort for limited gains... Api level 8 and above has 98.2% penetration in the Global Android market... You should really think long and hard whether your userbase constitutes a considerable amount of users below API 8 to be worth the effort for any application you might build.

Comment: Yes, I do have the API v1 key. The app had Maps API v1 before I moved to v2. @SamarthJain : yeah, I understand that. If it requires too much effort, I will not pursue it. Wanted to know if anyone had tried / implemented it.

Comment: @SamarthJain It really depends on the target. If Sap is targeting emerging markets, it is much higher than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply suggest creating a separate `Activity` for API v2 and doing something like this in `Activity` that starts maps:

```
if (isGles20() && isApi8()) {
    startNewActivity();
} else {
    startOldActivity();
}
```

You will get some duplicated code, but that's what refacoring is for to extract common logic into some class.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks! Its been a while since I have been coding, but I am not really good at code design. But still, I should have got this!